# check conditions against a variable in Jupyter

Tags: python, sql, pandas, jupyter

sharing the issue below. Using the below sql code in jupyter I am trying to come up  with some sort of the report. So basically numVH is a combination of these 6 variables listed below. The greater the numVH greater is the risk score - Each variable can have a value either 0 or 1. I want to come up with a Jupyter code that helps me identify what variable influenced numVH the most. Also if we could go a step further and check under which variable what parameter was met the most times (for eg. indIDTheftVH - what parameters under indIDTheftVH)

```
numVH = indIDTheftVH + indIDTheftVH2 + indRiskyEmailVH + indRiskyPhoneVH + indRiskyIPVH + indvoiPEmail


SELECT 

CASE WHEN VENDOR EMAILAGE_ SCORE >= 500 AND (VENDOR_ TMX SUMMARY RISK SCORE <= 0 OR APPLICANT TYPE = 'joint') AND VENDOR_WP_ IDENTITY_CHECK_SCORE >= 350 AND indPhoneMatchLoose - 0 THEN 1
ELSE 0 END AS indIDTheftVH,

CASE WHEN indPhoneMatchloose = 0 AND VENDOR_WP_IDENTITY_CHECK_SCORE >= 475 THEN 1
WHEN indPhoneMatchloose = 0 AND VENDOR_TMX_SUMMARY_RISK_SCORE 0 AND VENDOR_NP_NETWORK_SCORE>=0.9 THEN 1
WHEN indPhoneMatchloose - 0 AND (VENDOR_TMX_SUMMARY_RISK_SCORE <= 0 OR APPLICANT_TYPE = 'joint') AND VENDOR_EMAILAGE_SCORE >= 800 800 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS indIDTheftVH2,

CASE WHEN EMAILAGE_ DOMAIN_ COMPANY IN 'Yahoo Inc' AND EMAILAGE_FIRST_SEEN DAYS <= 60 AND EMAILAGE_NME_MTCH IN ('U','N') AND EMAILAGE_TOTAL_HITS >= 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS indRiskyEmailVH,

CASE WHEN indPhoneMatch = 0 AND NS_Phone_Activation IN ('I2','I3','I4','I5','I6','I7",'U,') AND VENDOR_WP_ IDENTITY_CHECK_SCORE >= 450 THEN 1
WHEN indPhoneMatch = 0 AND NS_Phone_Activation IN ('I2','I3','I4','I5','I6','I7','U,') AND VENDOR_NEUSTAR_ PHONESCORE < 70 AND VENDOR_NEUSTAR_PHONEVALIDATION = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS indRiskyPhoneVH,

CASE WHEN EMAILAGE_IP_RISK_LEVEL IN (`Very High','High') THEN 1
WHEN EMAILAGE_IP_REPUTATION = 'Very High Risk' THEN 1
WHEN EMAILAGE_IP_USER_TYPE = 'wired' THEN 1
WHEN EMAILAGE_IP_ANONYMOUS_DETECTED = 'Yes' THEN 1
ELSE 0 END AS indRiskyIPVH,

CASE WHEN (indTMx1 + indTMX2 + indTMx3 + indTMX4 + indTMx5 + indtHx6) >= 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS indTMXVH,

CASE WHEN VENDOR_WP_LINE_TYPE IN ('Non-fixed VOIP',' Fixed VOIP') AND VENDOR_EMAILAGE_SCORE >= 450 AND MARKETING CHANNEL NOT IN ('ag','sc','ds','partner','if`, 'em') THEN 1
WHEN VENDOR_NEUSTAR_VOIPIND IN (1.0,2.0,3.0) AND VENDOR_EMAILAGE_SCORE >= 450 AND MARKETING CHANNEL NOT IN ('ag','sc','ds','partner','if','em') THEN THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As indvoiPEmail,

(indIDTheftVH) + indIDTheftVH2 + indRiskyEmailVH + indRiskyPhoneVH + indRiskyIPVH + indvoiPEmail) as numVH

FROM abc
```